# How to add a custom cursor for a ASP.NET control?

Tags: asp.net, cursors

How can I add a custom mouse cursor (say cursors from C:\Windows\Cursors directory) onto a ASP.NET user control?

Thanks a bunch,

dattebayo...

Answer (score 2):

you can use the CSS `cursor` attribute (see [this page](http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm) for available cursors).

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style="cursor: pointer" />
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
  .PointerCursor
  {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="PointerCursor" />
```

Comment: Or to use custom cursor file: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/